# Slow Windows Updates on Windows servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I manage several servers running Windows 2008 R2. We install the latest Windows Updates every month. From the logs over the last year I can see that it is taking longer and longer to install them.

For example in 2013 it took 3 minutes to install 6 updates. Now it takes 15 minutes to install 6 updates.

It doesn't seem to be a particular update this is causing a problem. I have tried:

Setting Windows Updates to download the updates in advance.
Defragmenting the hard drive
Recreated the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download folder

I have checked the install as it runs and it does not seem to be the download but the actual installation that is slow.

Any ideas for speeding the installation up?

Comment: How and why is this a problem? It takes as long as it takes. The updates may be larger, the updates may have more "work" to do, etc. Are you tilting at windmills?

Comment: If *you* are applying updates, you're doing it wrong. *You* shouldn't have to do anything. This should be happening automatically via a configuration management system, update management system or script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause for the slow installation of Windows Updates was this registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Trace

There is a value there called "Level" set to 3.

It's not clear why this key was present on so many of our servers - it is not present on a new clean build of Windows. Perhaps it has been added by a particular Windows Update or one of the utilities we are using. It also raises the level of information logged to c:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log.

After removing the key and associated sub keys and values we have seen much faster times for the installation of Windows Updates. In fact they are installing 3 times as fast so I am satisfied that we have found the root cause. I hope this info is useful to someone!